# How to submit form with blank or empty values and non blank values in Laravel

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have modal pop up window with form, on submission of form I want to insert data whatever user has selected or entered. Currently I am not able to submit form unless I fill all the field and select any values from dropdown.

Here is my Html code:

```
<div id="feedbackModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" id="feedback_form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <span id="form_output"></span>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Adjust Risk Level:</label>
                      <select name="FeedRisklevel" id="FeedRisklevel" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Risk Level</option>
                        <option value="High Risk">High Risk</option>
                        <option value="Low Risk">Low Risk</option>
                      </select>       
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label>Influencers:</label><br/>
                      <select name="Feedinfluencers[]" id="Feedinfluencers" multiple class="form-control">
                        <option value="Long Work Hours">Long Work Hours</option>
                        <option value="No Vacation/Leaves in Recent past">No Vacation/Leaves in Recent past</option>
                        <option value="Salary not per market standards">Salary not per market standards</option>
                        <option value="Lower Salary than Peers">Lower Salary than Peers</option>
                        <option value="No Bonus Received in last one year
                        ">No Bonus Received in last one year</option>
                        <option value="No Salary Revision in last one year">No Salary Revision in last one year</option>
                        <option value="Expecting Relocation">Expecting Relocation</option>
                        <option value="Expecting Progression">Expecting Progression</option>
                        <option value="Looking for Role/Job/Unit change">Looking for Role/Job/Unit change</option>
                        <option value="Upskilling/Learning Programs Missing">Upskilling/Learning Programs Missing</option>
                        <option value="High Work Pressure/Stress">High Work Pressure/Stress</option>
                        <option value="Non-Alignment with Supervisors/Managers">Non-Alignment with Supervisors/Managers</option>
                        <option value="Lower Bonus received than expected in last one year">Lower Bonus received than expected in last one year</option>
                        <option value="Lower Salary Revision than expected in last one year">Lower Salary Revision than expected in last one year</option>
                        <option value="No Work Life Balance">No Work Life Balance</option>
                        <option value="Lack of Job Security">Lack of Job Security</option>
                        <option value="Lack of Recognition">Lack of Recognition
                        </option>
                        <option value="Lack of Career Opportunities">Lack of Career Opportunities</option>
                        <option value="Lack of Employee Care Activities">Lack of Employee Care Activities</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Employee Discussion Feedback:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="feedback" id="feedback" class="form-control" placeholder="Feedback" value="" />
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Action Taken:</label>
                        <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="Yes">Yes
                        <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="No" checked>No
                        <select name="action[]" id="action" multiple class="action form-control">
                          <option value="Offcycle Salary Revision">Offcycle Salary Revision</option>
                          <option value="Special Bonus">Special Bonus</option>
                          <option value="Retention Bonus">Retention Bonus</option>
                          <option value="Internal Career Opportunity">Internal Career Opportunity</option>
                          <option value="Monthly/Quarterly Recognition">Monthly/Quarterly Recognition</option>
                          <option value="Inline Progression">Inline Progression</option>
                          <option value="Stay Interview">Stay Interview</option>
                          <option value="One on one discussion/Counselling">One on one discussion/Counselling</option>
                          <option value="Personal Development Plan">Personal Development Plan</option>
                          <option value="Relocation Opportunity">Relocation Opportunity</option>
                          <option value="Flexibility in the Schedule">Flexibility in the Schedule</option>
                          <option value="Upskilling/Learning Programs Scheduled">Upskilling/Learning Programs Scheduled</option>
                          <option value="Workload Balanced">Workload Balanced</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>      
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                     <input type="hidden" name="feedback_id" id="feedback_id" value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="FeedRisklevel_id" id="FeedRisklevel_id" value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="Feedinfluencers_id" id="Feedinfluencers_id" value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="Action_id" id="Action_id" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="button_action" id="button_action" value="insert" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Feedback" value="Submit" class="btn" style="background-color: #CA0088;color: #fff" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
 $('#feedback_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('Predictions.store') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error.length > 0)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+data.error[count]+"</div>";
                    }
                    $('#form_output').html(error_html);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#form_output').html(data.success);
                    $('#feedback_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#feedback').val('');
                    $('#FeedRisklevel').val('');
                    $('#Feedinfluencers').val('');
                    $('#action').val('');
                    $('.modal-title').text('Submit Feedback');
                    $('#button_action').val('insert');
                    $('#members_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    { 

        // $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        //         'feedback' => 'required',
        //         'FeedRisklevel' => 'required',
        //         'Feedinfluencers' => 'required',
        //         'action' => 'required'
                
        //     ]);
            
            $error_array = array();
            $success_output = '';
            // if ($validation->fails())
            // {
            //     foreach ($validation->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $messages)
            //     {
            //         $error_array[] = $messages; 
            //     }
            // }
            // else
            // {
                if($request->get('button_action') == 'insert')
                {
                    $data = new Prediction([
                        'Feedback'    =>  $request->get('feedback'),
                        'Feedinfluencers' => $request->get('Feedinfluencers'),
                        'FeedRisklevel' => $request->get('FeedRisklevel'),
                        'Action' => $request->get('action')
                        
                    ]);
                    $data->save();
                    $success_output = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Data Inserted</div>";
                }

                if($request->get('button_action') == 'update')
                {
                    $data = Prediction::find($request->get('feedback_id'));
                    $data->Feedback = $request->get('feedback');
                    $data->save();

                    $data1 = Prediction::find($request->get('FeedRisklevel_id'));
                    $data1->FeedRisklevel = $request->get('FeedRisklevel');
                    $data1->save();

                    $data2 = Prediction::find($request->get('Feedinfluencers_id'));
                    $data2->Feedinfluencers = $request->get('Feedinfluencers');
                    $data2->save();

                    $data3 = Prediction::find($request->get('Action_id'));
                    $data3->Action = $request->get('action');
                    $data3->save();

                    $success_output = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thanks for your Feedback!</div>';
                }
                
            
            
            $output = array(
                'error'     =>  $error_array,
                'success'   =>  $success_output
            );
            echo json_encode($output);
        }
```

I am able to store data but have to select all the values what I need is it should submit the data whaterver user have selected if it is blank it should insert blank data in DB. Can someone help me out how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Firstly make all fields as nullable in database table.
Step 2: After that modify your select tag as:

```
<select name="Feedinfluencers[]" id="Feedinfluencers" multiple class="form-control">
   

> <option value="">Select</option>

   <option value="Long Work Hours">Long Work Hours</option>
   <option value="No Vacation/Leaves in Recent past">No Vacation/Leaves in Recent past</option>
   .
   .
</select>
```

Step 3: change other select as per your code:

```
<select name="action[]" id="action" multiple class="action form-control">
   

> <option value="">Select</option>

   <option value="Offcycle Salary Revision">Offcycle Salary Revision</option>
   <option value="Special Bonus">Special Bonus</option>
```

After this you can add or upadte nullable fields

Apart from that if you want to add or update data direct you can above code:
Step 1:
In App\Model make specific changes as:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;

class Prediction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'prediction';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

}
```

Step 2: After this you can directly use in controller as:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->get('button_action') == 'insert')
      {
          $param = $request->all();
          $param['button_action'] = 'insert'; // if you want to overload you field with new data
          $prediction= Prediction::create($param);
      }
      if($request->get('button_action') == 'update')
      {
         $param = $request->all();
          $param['button_action'] = 'update'; // if you want to overload you field with new data
          $prediction= Prediction::where('id',$id)->update($param);
      }
     }
```

Above is the snippet example for your code you can use it as per you requirments.